# SELECT query data visibility in MySQL

Tags: mysql

Which data will be visible to SELECT statement executed out of explicit transaction? Won't it see uncommitted data from? Are there any settings to change it?

Comment: The entire point of transactions is that, no, you can't. What did you think that they are?

Comment: But select is executed inside transaction, implicit transaction

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on the transaction level set for your DB. By default in mysql, it is [REPEATABLE READ](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/set-transaction.html#isolevel_repeatable-read).

Just check this article to read more about the transaction levels.
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/set-transaction.html

Answer (score 1):

You cannot see uncommitted data, that would defeat the purpose of Atomicity.